# DotCover "cover" command takes hours to generate snapshot

Tags: wpf, nunit, nunit-3.0, dotcover

I have an UI automation for a WPF windows app. And our management decided to use dotCover to calculate coverage.
I'm trying to get application coverage after a simple test running using command line. Here is it:

```
dotcover.exe cover coverage.xml
```

Coverage.xml file content looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CoverageParams>
  <TargetExecutable>nunit3-console.exe</TargetExecutable>
  <TargetArguments>CI.UIAutomationTests.dll --where="test =~ /TC100/" --agents=1 --workers=1 --labels=All</TargetArguments>
  <TargetWorkingDir></TargetWorkingDir>
  <TempDir><!-- Directory for auxiliary files. Set to the system temp by default. --></TempDir>
  <Output>ClientCoverage_TC100.snapshot</Output>
  ...
```

Test was executed successfully, took about 2+ min. But then it stops for about 2-3 hours and if i will let it work i will get the snapshot as a result:

```
Test Run Summary
Overall result: Failed
Test Count: 1, Passed: 0, Failed: 1, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
Failed Tests - Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Invalid: 0
Start time: 2017-10-23 07:41:57Z
End time: 2017-10-23 07:45:28Z
Duration: 211.288 seconds

Results (nunit3) saved as TestResult.xml
[JetBrains dotCover] Coverage session finished [10/23/2017 10:49:11 AM]
[JetBrains dotCover] Analyzed application exited with code '1'
[JetBrains dotCover] Coverage results post-processing started [10/23/2017 10:49:11 AM]
[JetBrains dotCover] Coverage results post-processing finished [10/23/2017 10:49:12 AM]
```

So the question is: why it takes so long?

Answer (score 0):

I think it analyses all your 3rd-party dependencies.  Have you tried filtering it to only analyse assemblies with your namespace? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Running_Coverage_Analysis_from_the_Command_LIne.html#filters_xml?section=

Comment: Thanks for the response! It was another reason. The application under test launches another app and it didn't closed after test finishes. When i decided to close it - i realized that dot.cover not stuck anymore.
So, the solution is - close all the sub-processes of app under test.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The application under test launches another app and it didn't closed after test finishes. When i decided to close it - i realized that dot.cover not stuck anymore. 
So, the solution is - close all the sub-processes of app under test